# I want to sort a generic stack of "HighlightedCellRecords" using Collections.sort but get runtime error

Tags: java, sorting, generics, linked-list, stack

I've not used `Collections.sort` before. Maybe I can't use it to sort my generic stack of objects. I found a promising example [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/sort-linkedlist-of-user-defined-objects-in-java/), and it compiled, but I got a runtime error, shown below the code.

```
package gbl;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class HighightedCellRecord implements Comparable<HighightedCellRecord>{
  char content;
  int row,
      col;
  Color foreground,
        background;
  boolean isVertex;

  public HighightedCellRecord() { }

  public HighightedCellRecord(char ch, int r, int c, Color f, Color b){//, 

    content    = ch;
    row        = r;
    col        = c;
    foreground = f;
    background = b;
    isVertex   = false;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(HighightedCellRecord o) 
  {
    if(this.row == o.row)
    {
      if      (this.col >  o.col) return 1;
      else if (this.col == o.col) return 0;
      else                        return -1;
    }
    else  
    {
      if      (this.row >  o.row) return 1;
      else if (this.row == o.row) return 0;
      else                        return -1;
    }
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "<" + content + "> @ (" + row + "," + col + ")";
  }  

  public String toWrite(){
    return content + "," + row + "," + col;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    GenericStack<HighightedCellRecord> s ;

    s = new GenericStack<>();

    s.push(new HighightedCellRecord('O', 3, 7, null, null));
    s.push(new HighightedCellRecord('D', 3, 9, null, null));
    s.push(new HighightedCellRecord('W', 3, 6, null, null));
    s.push(new HighightedCellRecord('R', 3, 8, null, null));

/////////////////// error on next line /////////////////////////////

    Collections.sort((List<HighightedCellRecord>) s);

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
      System.out.println(s.find(i));
  }

}
```

...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
gbl.GenericStack cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at gbl.HighightedCellRecord.main(HighightedCellRecord.java:58)
Java Result: 1
```

However, I came up with a workaround, and I don't know if it's the only way. Here's modified `main` (from just below point of error shown above):

```
t = new LinkedList<>();

while(s.isNotEmpty())
  t.add(s.pop());

Collections.sort(t);

while(! t.isEmpty())
  s.push(t.pop());
```

I realize that, by definition and concept, stacks differ from linked lists differ from queues, **but I don't quite understand why I couldn't use `Collections.sort` on a stack,** which is just a special type of linked list, isn't it, as shown by the first few lines of the definition of my generic stack:

```
public class GenericStack<E>  {  

  public LinkedList <E> stack = new LinkedList<>();
```

**Is the bottom line that, if I need it to be sorted, it shouldn't be a stack?**

**Is there a way to directly sort my stack?** IF not, I'll see how much effort needs to go into changing it to a simple linked list. (I use three other stacks in the program: one for undo, one for redo, and another for transactions. I guess I got carried away.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `GenericStack` is not a `List`; it contains a `List`.

Presumably you implement the `push(...)` method by adding to the front of the `LinkedList`; just take the same approach to sorting:

```
public class GenericStack<E> {

   // you should really make this private; 
   //you want to hide your implementation
   public LinkedList<E> stack = new LinkedList<>(); 


   // ...
   public void sort() {
       Collections.sort(stack);
   }
}
```

And then instead of calling `Collections.sort((List<...>)s);` just call `s.sort()`

Your other option would be to make `GenericStack` implement `List`. Or, just use a `LinkedList` directly, since it implements [`DeQue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html).

Comment: @James_D--Thanks for mentioning about GenericStack not BEING, but CONTAINING a list. And I will see if I can make it work using your suggestion rather than faking it or redesigning.

Comment: What's wrong with using a `LinkedList`? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @James--I intend to alter the program to make the needs-sorting object a LinkedList instead of a stack. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the javadoc for `Collections.sort` it requires a `List<>` as an argument. Since a `Stack` is not a `List` it won't work. While both `Stack` and `List` derive from `AbstractList` they still are not interchangeable.

As a rule, when you're dealing with `Collections` and end up need to cast your collection, you should probably stop and ask yourself why. While you will probably be able to get it to compile, getting it 1) to run and 2) do what you expect is going to be a long shot.

You could certainly write you own sort logic for `Stack` but I would question why you would want to do that. The `Stack` contract is design to preserve the insertion order of its elements. When you need to throw that away you're probably better off reconsidering some of your design choices.

Comment: @Baldy--thank you. You cleared up any misconception I had and cemented my guess that I should have just made HighlightedStack a list in the first place. And you are right: I really should begin looking at--make that STUDYING--Javadocs.

Comment: I also plead guilty and have absolutely no excuse for making stuff public when I know better.